# PHP 5.5.27 - array of rows within array from one column's common data - how to?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I am fairly new to php. Please excuse me if my terms are not correct. I can use and see lots of examples of arrays that loop table rows (all columns).

I want to create/display information from a table like this:

Table example

```
1, John, Test, bb, cc, dd
2, John, Fram, ee, ff, gg
3, John, Whop, hh, ii, jj
4, Chris, Test, kk, ll, mm
5, Chris, Fram, nn, oo, pp
6, Chris, Whop, qq, rr, ss
```

(this table will have many more rows and many more names)

Results I want

```
John
Test, bb, cc, dd
Fram, ee, ff, gg
Whop, hh, ii, jj

Chris
Test, kk, ll, mm
Fram, nn, oo, pp
Whop, qq, rr, ss
```

(and on and on throughout the whole table)

I have been starting with this code to retrieve the data from the table -

```
$q = "SELECT id, name, type, data1, data2, data3 FROM table";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
```

Where should I proceed from this point?

Comment: Order SQL by name. In your loop keep track of last name extracted for the row, once different, start a new group and update last name.

Comment: Edited formatting (HTML -> Markdown, code-inline->code-block). Also, generally better to ask for an answer instead of an outside resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok your existing 2 statement create and issue a query for execution by MySQL.

You now need to request data back from the database one row at a time so you can do something with the result rows

```
$q = "SELECT id, name, type, data1, data2, data3 FROM table ORDER BY name";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

// first lets check we got a result and not an error
if ( ! $result ) {
    echo mysqli_error($dbc);
    exit;
}

// get one result row at a time as an object
// each returned row will be an object with 
// properties with the same names as the 
// column names of the query we are processing

$lastName = NULL;

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_object($result) ) {
    // build required output

    if ( $lastname != $row->name ) {
        echo '<br>' . $row->name . '<br>';

        $lastName = $row->name;
    }

    echo $row->type . ', '
       . $row->data1 . ', '
       . $row->data2 . ', '
       . $row->data3 . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you RiggsFolly for the reply. I will experiment with this, but won't your suggestion repeat the "name" again after the break? I do not want to repeat the name, I want to treat it sort-of like a header for the group of rows.

Comment: After a quick test, unfortunately this is no solution for me. It loops the "name" with each row. I wish to loop the "type, data1, data2, data3" for each time the "name" occurs in a row.

Comment: Oh i see, give me a minute

Comment: Unfortunately, your edit removing the name after the break does not work either. Your suggestion loops a group that is essentially one row, including the name. I want to loop all of the rows associated with one "name" data. And then loop that *whole* result (a set of looped rows for *each* name). Effectively, I am trying to create a "header" for a group of rows. Thank you, I appreciate the help.

Comment: Yea I see, try that. Make sure you chnage the query also to add the `order by`

Comment: Fundamentally, this solves what I have asked. I really appreciate the help RiggsFolly. ! To understand, you have created a variable ($lastName) that updates it's value to the current result, thus returning the *next* "name" result each time it loops. Correct? Or, is it just removing the "name" result from the loop as as the other row data is being looped?

Comment: No it just does not show the Name column if it has already been shown. Each result row is processed, but only the `type,data1,dat2,data2` columns are shown when the same `name` appears in the next result row. Correct results depend upon the result being sorted on the `name`

Comment: Well, that is exactly what I want to see data-wise. However, it seems a little tricky to be able to format, to display column data within a table or css columns. For that purpose, is it possible to create these results from arrays? A "main" looped-array of names, and "sub" arrays with are the rows of other associated columns. ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$johnQuery = "SELECT type, data1, data2, data3 FROM table WHERE name = 'John'";

$chrisQuery = "SELECT type, data1, data2, data3 FROM table WHERE name = 'Chris'";

$john = mysqli_query($dbc, $johnQuery);

$chris= mysqli_query($dbc, $chrisQuery);
```

You want like this?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This does not solve my problem. My table will have hundreds of rows and hundreds of names. I cannot write a query for each one. I want to group (and loop) results based on common data from one column.